# GCS - Secure Way to Authenticate to GCS From On-Premises Server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil, google-cloud-storage

I am looking for the secure/recommended way to connect and perform actions on GCS.

**Need:**

We have files on an on-premises Linux environment that needs to be uploaded to GCS on a hourly basis. Newer files alone will need to be uploaded. Multiple users/processes use the server. Manual intervention or authentication is not possible. Ok to have one-time authentication setup.

**Current Implementation:**

A simple shell script using service account as shown below. Script is authenticated using the JSON key file of the service account with access to the storage account.

```bash
gsutil -m rsync -r -P -e <LINUX_PATH> <GCS_PATH>
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the safest and recommended way to authenticate from an on-premises linux server outside of GCP to connect to GCS?
2. Is there a better way to handle the authentication without downloading the key file? I understand that if an intruder gets access to the server, we are done for anyways, but still would be nice if we had a better option.

**Update:**

In case Service Account Key file is the only options, please suggest the recommended way to secure the file. Currently we limit the permission of the file to the user executing the shell script. Any other options would be appreciated.

3. We had considered "Service Account Impersonation". But in this case, how are we supposed to login to the user having only the `serviceAccountTokenCreator` role. We would once again need to resort to JSON key file?

3.1. In case of Service Account Impersonation, is the allowed time defaulted to 60 minutes?

Comment: Since your system is located outside GCP, you need credentials. The recommended approach is a service account. You can grant access to only one bucket to minimize impact if the service account is compromised. Start with this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam)

Comment: I do not recommend impersonation in your case. That would store a user's credentials on the system with privileges to a service account. That can increase risk and require more steps to set up and manage. I wrote an [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/) on impersonation with more details.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley. Thank you for your response. From the comment, can I assume that the only recomm. way to connect from an on-premises RHEL server to GCS is through a Srvc Acct Key (JSON File). I had looked at the [flowchart](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#auth-decision-tree) and had hoped for a better way. **Follow Up Qn:** Can you please suggest a good way to secure the key file? Currently we limit the permission of the file to the user executing the shell script. Any other options avl ? Any encryption/b64 encoding options? Open to trying out any other options too.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Went through the article and had also hoped if I can use impersonation, but I had similar thoughts about leaving the Srvc Acct (with create token) with permission to use another Srvc Acct (with bucket access), hence the question...The tiger was too cool...

Comment: How well do you understand Google Cloud IAM and security in general? In security, I prefer to keep things simple. Easier to document, implement, manage, and detect problems. If your goal is to protect from a breach, you will have issues. Once the hacker is inside, they can access anything on the machine. Encryption will not help as the key must be stored as well. The more parts you implement the more likely YOU will make a mistake. Minimize the damage that can be done. Use a service account and grant it the minimum permissions necessary to do its job. Rotate the service account key often.

Comment: Review service account policy constraints. This can add another layer of protection: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts

Comment: Review IAM conditions. You can add conditions such as a service account only works during certain times. That can confuse an attacker. If used outside supported hours, the attacker would think the service account is not valid and move on to the next item. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview

Comment: @JohnHanley, thank you for your response. We considered it, but unfortunately this is a script expected to be triggered every hour via cron, (24x7). In your experience is there anything you have come across to secure the key file on the server ? Encryption ? server based vault ? encoding ? scoped access ? anything ? - I was hoping that this was a common use case - having to load files from on-premises server to GCS - is everyone using the SA key file working with such risks ?

Comment: I have provided links to documentation. Study those. If your server is not secure then do not put secrets on it. Secure the server first.   Yes, using credentials of some type is required. As I mentioned encryption will not help as that is just another secret on the server to protect.

Comment: If the server is breached, you can only minimize the blast radius as I already mentioned. I recommend you get someone experienced with security to work with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256723/discussion-between-rainingdistros-and-john-hanley).

Comment: I don’t have more to say. When you have implemented a solution and have a problem, post another question.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can do [uploads in GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#uploads). As to your script, you are using single-request upload type. You may want to check the following ways:

- [Resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads), which can use OAuth 2.0 and XML configuration.
- [Streaming uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming-uploads), which uses checksum validation when streaming.

Just remember that everytime additional security that you configure with your system, there can be added complexity on implementing it.

Comment: Thank you for your response and links. I will consider these options; However, I am looking for a better way to authenticate to GCS from an on-premises server. Performance is not an issue at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the service account key in a file is the simplest solution, but you have risks associated with access to that file.

If your Linux machine uses another identity service, you should look into [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#wlif). With it the authentication task moves to your identity provider, and on Google you grant that identity access to Google Cloud resources, or allow it to impersonate a service account. No service account key file required.